# X11 forwarding without putty

Tags: x11-forwarding

I am trying to use x11 forwarding from a Redhat server to a Windows 10 VM to display firefox. The client has requested that no additional software be used on the VM so i cannot use exceed or putty. Is there a way to do this without the additional software?

Comment: This isn't a programming problem. You should ask on https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a way, there are some alternatives though:

- use another SSH client: MobaXterm has X11 forwarding integrated (https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/)
- if you're using a specific tool, there might be a web-server version of it, that can be accessed by a browser on your WX machine, e.g. rstudio-server or any kind of Jupyter notebook (R / Python / several others).
- I don't have experience with this - maybe there is a RDP compatible server for Linux that can be accessed with the Windows remote desktop tool.

Comment: btw. MobaXterm has a portable edition that doesn't need to be installed!

Answer (score 0):

On the Redhat server you can install CloudTk which lets you view X11 program in a web browser via noVNC. See

https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/CloudTk

Therefore in your Windows VM just use the default browser installed.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has not a built in X-server so, if you want to go with X11-forwarding, you must install one on your Windows machine (`VcXsrv` or `Xming` are both good choices).
Putty can be avoided using the windows 10 built in `SSH` client. Just check if it is enabled in windows features and follow [@Aamir Sultan's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73561531/13338157) (second paragraph).

If you don't want to install an X-server on windows, I suggest to go with RDP protocol:

1. Install xrdp on RedHat server (I suppose you already have a desktop environment installed there, otherwise you need one installed too)
2. Use windows' built in remote desktop connection client to connect to your Ubuntu server desktop and run GUI apllication inside it.

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

If you can use the `VcXsrv` or `Xming` for the display on windows (I know you are saying that you can't install additional softwares but I wonder how would you create X server display other than `VcXsrv` or `Xming` on Windows. Pardon me for my limited knowledge.). There might be a way. Create directory named `dev` at `C:\` and create an empty file `tty` in the `dev`. The hierarchy should look like `C:\dev\tty`.

Open `Powershell` and run the command `$env:DISPLAY='localhost:0.0'` in it. ssh your server from Powershell via command `ssh -vvvY <username>@<server-IP>`. This should print debug information and trusted X11 forwarding access to the server. After successful login try something graphical like in your case `firefox` or `gedit` to test out the connection.

Working for me. One can try the same procedure with bash also. Only difference is that one is needed to export the DISPLAY variable like `export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0` in the terminal and remaining process is the same. Bash terminal are normally available with `git for widows` or `cmder` with basic functionalities.